# how to implement pinch zoom in javascript without using any external library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Does anyone know of a really good Javascript pinch-zooming algorithm?
This is trickier than I had imagined, as you have to scale -AND-
translate to keep the pinch zooming centered between your fingers.

And I want it to do pure translation when the user moves two fingers -
kept an equal distance apart from each other - around the screen,
i.e., this moving two fingers in unison should act like a single-
finger "pan".
scale factor = distance between end point cursor / distance between initial point cursor
distance between start cursor pointer = √((start cursor pointerx2-start cursor pointerx1)^2 * (start cursor pointery2-start cursor pointery1)^2)

Comment: You can get started with [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events). Then try searching the web for resources on implementing zooming.

Comment: already did . I'm facing issue while translating the img . any resource recommendation ?